# How to update Chrubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, updates, chromebook

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.5 through Crouton on my Chromebook, and I can't seem to make it update. As in, I can't find a way to update from 12.04.5 to a more recent version. Also I have only tried

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Is this the right command?
Please tell me how to do this, if there is a way! I can't do Unity-specific stuff, BTW. I have xfce4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

won't update your system in any way, it will just make sure the system is aware of the most recent versions of packages in the ubuntu repositories. You should always use this command before any upgrade commands.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

will install the newest versions of packages possible without changing your system.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

will update packages and handle their dependencies, which could make some parts of your system stop working, though normally only if you've configured it in an unusual way. This command will also do point release upgrades, that is 12.04.5 to 12.04.6 (if it exists)

The command to change to a newer release is:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Be careful with all of these commands, as soon as you use sudo, you're operating like the root user, so can damage your system if you type a command wrongly!

Comment: Thanks! But sudo do-release-upgrade didn't quite work...

Comment: 12.04.5 to 14.04+

Comment: Likewise.  Command does not exist on chrubuntu.